# Hartl's rails tutorial error "Couldn't find User with id=#<User:0x00000007472a28>"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working through Michael Hartl's ruby on rails tutorial without too much trouble (at least not much I haven't been able to solve with a bit of looking/thinking/searching) but I'm stuck on an error I get when trying to implement the relationships model in chapter 11.

Specifically, hitting the follow/unfollow button returns the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in RelationshipsController#create
Couldn't find User with id=#<User:0x007f3288020d98>
Extracted source (around line #5):

def create
@user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
current_user.follow!(@user)
redirect_to @user
end
```

I can tell that the problem is that the userid it's searching should just be an integer, not anything like #, but I'm not sure why it's searching something that looks like a hex code instead of the userid.

The RelationshipsController is exactly the same as given in the tutorial:

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
    redirect_to @user
  end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow!(@user)
    redirect_to @user
  end
end
```

The only significant difference I can think of is that I'm using postgres instead of sqlite, but since switching to postgres was given as an exercise I can't imagine it would cause this sort of problem.

I tried searching for similar issues, but I couldn't find anything - any help would be great.

(edit)

The form that renders the follow/unfollow buttons is:

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
    <div id="follow_form">
        <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
            <%= render 'unfollow' %>
        <% else %>
            <%= render 'follow' %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

And the buttons themselves:

```
<%= form_for (current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @user)) do |f| %>
    <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
    <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

and

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.find_by(followed_id: @user), html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn btn-large" %>
<% end %>
```

The show method of the UsersController is

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :following, :followers]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user, only: :destroy
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
    if current_user?(@user)
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.build
    end
  end
  .
  .
  .
```

Comment: Can you post your view that renders the button? Your `user` object is being converted to a string instead of getting the user id in your button/link creation is my guess.

Comment: `#<User:0x007f3288020d98>` is the to_s of a (*non integer/id*) User object .. yet "find by id" requires such an (usually integer) id and *not* an instance of said object type being sought!

Comment: Please show the code from the view for the button and also the show method in the controller.

Comment: Thanks for the replies - updated with the requested code

Comment: ...and in doing so, I realized what I did wrong - the Follow partial needed to use (followed_id: @user.id) instead of just (followed_id: @user)  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the id of the user not the user object itself so change the partial for the `follow` to have:

`followed_id: @user.id` instead of `followed_id: @user`